# MS Visual Studio 13 Forms SQL Server 2008 V2 slow query return

Tags: visual-studio, performance

I've been doing some timings on running stored procedures using VS and MS Server Mgmnt Studio.

I run my sp through SSMS first from my PC to the SQL Server will run in about 7 seconds, no  problems.

When I then run the same sp through VS using a windows form, a dataset and a sqlclient cmd and attach to a datagridivew the results takes 25 second to come back?

Is this normal? i.e.  nearly 4 times as long ?

Comment: You are _probably_ falling foul of parameter sniffing. [This](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) is an extensive article explaining the issue and possible corrective action. It is a painful road ahead...

Comment: Hi Paddy,I checked my two stored procedurecausing te problem and there are no parameters, they just return a simple query of all record sin the table with a number of left joins, returning around 3000 rows of about 10 columns!
Any other ideas I may turn my sp into View which may work faster!!! Although I read online it wouldn't make a difference!

Comment: Just to check, it's _just_ the query that takes 4x longer to run in the App. That's not including the additional time for mapping and databinding etc? In short I'm not sure what it could be. I'd be interested to hear any results from your investigations.